# Extracting specific alphanumeric patterns from a long string

Tags: python, arrays, regex, string, regex-group

I want to match group number and their lines group from a text similar this:

```
domain 1 
654789 text (one or more lines)
domain 2
125478 text (one or more lines)
```

I want to get:

```
domain 1 654789
domain 2 125478
```

My code is:

```
import re
from re import match

domain = re.compile(r'[-+]?domain')
terminal = re.compile(r'^[0-9][0-9]{6}(?!\d)')        
with open('in_texto.txt') as file_in:
    for linea in file_in:
        for match in re.finditer(domain, linea):
            dom = re.findall('\d+', linea)[0]
            print(dom)
            for lineas in file_in:
                for match in re.finditer(terminal, lineas):
                    print(dom+" "+lineas, end='')
```

But It only prints:

```
654789 text
956478 text
125478 text
 .....
```

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using the module `regex` (it actually works exactly the same using `re`)

```
# import regex  # or re - then subsitute regex.split for re.split etc.
# string = 'domain 1 \ntotal.....\n======= \n\n654789 text \n956478 text\ndomain 2\n======= \ncolumn..... \n\n\n125478 text \n456987 text '

domains = regex.split(r'domain \d+', string)
out = list()
for k in range(1, len(domains)):
    out.extend(['domain {} {}'.format(k, d) for d in regex.findall(r'\d+(?=\s*text)', domains[k])])
out
# ['domain 1 654789', 'domain 1 956478', 'domain 2 125478', 'domain 2 456987']
```

- First we split the raw text string by domains.
- Then for each domain we get the digits using the regex `\d+(?=\s*text)`.
- We finally process the extracted digits, add the corresponding domain and append the result to our list.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to first extract the domains. This works by spotting the domain line and then all text up to the next domain line. It then splits each of these into lines and extracts just the lines starting with 6 digits:

```
import re

terminal = re.compile(r'(\d+){6}\s+')  

with open('in_texto.txt') as file_in:
    for domain, lines in re.findall(r'^(domain\s+\d+?)(.*?)(?=^domain|\Z)', file_in.read(), re.M + re.S):
        for line in lines.splitlines():
            t = terminal.match(line)

            if t:
                print(domain, t.group())
```

This would give you something like:

```
domain 1 654789 
domain 1 956478 
domain 2 125478 
domain 2 456987 
domain 2 236512 
domain 3 369852 
domain 3 548723
```